# How do you know which jQuery library to include

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I make jQuery scripts I never know which jQuery library I have to include for example: the one from google or from jquery.com and then another problem appears do I have to include 1.4.4 or 1.4.2 etc.. jQuery library
So, how do I know which jQuery I have to include?

Comment: 1.4.4 is about five years old, so that's probably not the one you're looking for. Just include the newest one from google -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XKGbe/

Comment: You should use the latest version.  (but see the documentation on IE8 compatibility)

Comment: If you're using old code, you can use jQuery Migrate which will tell you which features are deprecated. It can help you find the right version or know what code needs updating.